# Ways to update a sql server database from a VC++ win32 project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, active-directory, passwords

I'm in the process of creating a Password Filter [as described here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/LoginFilter.aspx). I can manage to write the VC++ code. My issue is that i need to update SQL Server database from that code. I dont have any past experience in VC++ Win32 project. My assumptions are

1. Linking an external dll (compiled
   C#.net code) which will take care of
   the database update
2. Hitting a windows service which will
   take care of the update

   Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are those your only two options?

You can use ADO from directly within C++ by #import(ing) msado15.dll, which exposes lots of useful objects and methods from ADO.  See: [Visual C++ ADO Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675103%28VS.85%29.aspx)

There are other options here: [Data Access Programming in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd4ck1tt%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Since i dont have good working in knowledge in VC++ i found this solution to be more easy for me to do. Just followed [this Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736/en-us) to register a managed dll and create a type library and to use it in the VC++ code.

Anyways thanks for your reply joe.

NLV